# Defining a border width in PX vs EM on a responsive design

Tags: html, css

My entire stylesheet is all done using `em` instead of `px`. The entire theme is responsive.

The only thing that I have seen I would like to change to `px` is with a class that adds a border:

```
.border {
   border-width: 0.1em;
   border-style: solid;
}
```

The `0.1em` seems a little thick in most places. I would like to change this to `px`:

```
.border {
   border-width: 1px;
   border-style: solid;
}
```

I know I am probably being overly picky here, but is there any reason I shouldn't use `px` when defining a border width? If so, is there any way I can get that `0.1em` down a little smaller to look more like `1px`?

Comment: Hmm, how much are they different? In my demo they look identical https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/91s30yo4/ what if you try `0.09em` instead of `0.1em`?

Comment: If you want a 1px border...use a 1px border....there's no need to get fancy about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining it in em, which you have said you're not happy with, define it in px but change the value to 2px or 3px, etc., as the site changes via media queries. Then you have definite control.

```
@media screen and (min-width:30em) { .border {border:1px;} }
@media screen and (min-width:50em) { .border {border:2px;} }
```

The disadvantage is if you are wanting small increments in the screen size and your CSS becomes book length. Then you are just being overly picky.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `px` if you want your border width to be responsive.  `Px` is a fixed-size unit and will be constant despite any other responsive changes.  Thus, you run the risk of having tiny or large border widths relative to the rest of the page.

Did you test how the `1px` looks when your `font-size` (`em` scales with `font-size`) increases or decreases?

Comment: From the question title and description, it seems pretty clear that the questioner knows the difference between px and em. What he doesn't know is why despite we use relative units (em and rem, etc) for so many CSS properties, it's not been recommended to use it for ‍‍‍‍`border‍` property and it has been suggested to use fixed-size unit px, instead?